Hyperlink column with icon instead of text in a classic SharePoint list
I created a Power Automate Flow that uses the SharePoint connecter, "Send HTTP request" to create a custom hyperlink using a dynamic list value. I'd like to use an image or icon instead of a text value for the hyperlink.
How do I modify my variable I'm using in the http request to show the image? This is in a Classic SharePoint list, not modern.


Is there any way to make the emoji larger of more prominent? Such as using CSS to increase the size or change the color? The emoji for a document is small. 

You will not be able to add image in "Description" of SharePoint list hyperlink column using "Send HTTP Request to SharePoint" action in Power Automate.
However, you can add emoji in the "Description" of SharePoint list hyperlink column.
This is what worked for me:

Body:
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.306986ListItem"
    },
    "Hyperlink": {
        "Description": "",
        "Url": "https://www.google.com/"
    }
}

Output:


Additional Information:
You might be able to customize the hyperlink column display in SharePoint classic list view using Client Side Rendering (CSR) to show image in list view column and open hyperlink on click of image.
Check below references for CSR:

How to color code a SharePoint list date field based on comparison with todays date?
How to Highlight a Row on Active Status
Client-Side Rendering/JS Link documentation?


OMG, that worked!!!! BRILLIANT Thank you so much.

Great, I am glad it worked for you!

Please accept my above response as an Answer as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. Thanks!

IIRC, the classic SharePoint list column is called "hyperlink or picture". You can use the URL to point to an online picture or use it as a text hyperlink. The description for a hyperlink can only contain text, not images.
